# Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.8, mysql-error-1048

[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMr9I.jpg)

[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMr9I.jpg)

Hello I have an error in my database. the user registers in the users table and now he has to post an ad. I'm trying to get his id in the ads table. 
But it returns me this error:

> SQLSTATE [23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
>   'user_id' can not be null (SQL: insert into`ads` (`user_id`,
>   `services`, `head`,`level_study`, `language`,`experience`,
>   `localization`,`description`, `contact`,`updated_at`, `created_at`)
>   values ​​(?, Household, Housekeeper, BAC + 2, a little, 2years,
>   Yopougon, pnjjjk , 09789070, 2019-06-05 08:31:38, 2019-06-05
>   08:31:38))

```
public function store(Adstore $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validated();
    $user_id = Auth::user()['id'];
    $ad = new Ad();
    $ad->user_id = $user_id;
    $ad->services = $validated['dropdown_service'];
    $ad->titre = $validated['title'];
    $ad->niveau_etude = $validated['dropdown_etude'];
    $ad->langue = $validated['langue'];
    $ad->experience = $validated ['experience'];
    $ad->localisation = $validated ['local'];
    $ad->description = $validated ['description'];
    $ad->contact = $validated ['contact'];
    $ad->save();
    return redirect()->route('accueil')->with('success','Votre annonce a été postée.');
}
```

Comment: What does `$user_id` contain? `var_dump($user_id);`

Comment: Try dumping the content of `$user_id` using `dd($user_id);`. Also consider dumping the entire user object: `dd(Auth::user());` Can you post the result?

Comment: Try $user_id = Auth::user()->id instead Auth::user()['id'];
    Btw, small optimization: use mass assignable instead of individual property assignment. It will be way cleaner.

Comment: When I do this here is the error: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object
And if I put in comment
// $ user_id = Auth :: user () -> id;
and I dump like that dd (Auth :: user ());
I have this result: null.

Comment: You need to get authenticated first in order to use `Auth::user()`

Answer (score 0):

Make some changes in code as per below:

In controller:

```
public function store(Adstore $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validated();

    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    $ad = Ad::create([
        'user_id' => $user_id,        
        'services' => $validated['dropdown_service'],        
        'titre' => $validated['title'],        
        'niveau_etude' => $validated['dropdown_etude'],        
        'langue' => $validated['langue'],        
        'experience' => $validated['experience'],        
        'localisation' => $validated['local'],        
        'description' => $validated['description'],        
        'contact' => $validated['contact'],        
    ]);

    if($ad){
        return redirect()->route('accueil')->with('success','Votre annonce a été postée.');
    } else {
        return redirect()->route('accueil')->with('error','Something went wrong.');
    }    
}
```

Comment: The guy, there is really a big problem because I'm doing a dd (Auth :: user ()) I have a result null

Answer (score 0):

You have to access auth user id like this $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

Comment: I do not have access

Comment: public function login(Request $request)
    {

        $phone=$request->phone;
        if (Auth::attempt(['phone' => $phone]) )
        {
            //return redirect()->intended('/');
            dd(Auth::user());
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect()->back()->with( 'error', "Echec!" );
        }

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "$user_id = Auth::user()['id'];" use this : "$user_id = Auth::user()->id;"
it will work.

Comment: It does not work,"Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"

Comment: My apologies for this time out, I was a little unwell.
I managed to register my user even when I do dd (Auth :: user ()) it returns me a good result. But I have another concern to connect an existing user. I have one field and I want him to connect with the phone number he used for his registration.

Comment: public function authentification(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->isMethod('post')) {
            $data = $request->all();
            if (Auth::attempt(['phone' => $data['phone']])) {
                return redirect('/accueil');
            }
            else
            {
               return redirect()->back()->with('error','Veuillez vous inscrire!');
            }
        }
    }